# Confused about degrees of freedom

Tags: statistical-power, degrees-of-freedom

Everything I've read about degrees of freedom says more is better - it is an indication of a model's flexibility.

I'm now running a power analysis in R and I've noticed that lower degrees of freedom give higher power.

Example 1 (DF = N - 1):

```
library(pwr)

pwr.chisq.test(w = 0.7, N = 30, df = 29, sig.level = 0.05)

     Chi squared power calculation 

              w = 0.7
              N = 30
             df = 29
      sig.level = 0.05
          power = 0.5115032

NOTE: N is the number of observations
```

Example 2 (DF = 1):

```
pwr.chisq.test(w = 0.7, N = 30, df = 1, sig.level = 0.05) 

     Chi squared power calculation 

              w = 0.7
              N = 30
             df = 1
      sig.level = 0.05
          power = 0.9695413

NOTE: N is the number of observations
```

I assume in this case DF is supposed to refer to the number of parameters? If that's correct, why is it also used as sample size minus parameters?

Comment: What exactly did you learn about degrees of freedom and where? It definitely is not the case that "always more is better", so the claim is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

What software are you using? Or more exact how did you compute the power.

You can check here:
https://www.statskingdom.com/33test_power_regression.html

that increasing you sample size, increases you power.

Comment: I used pwr.chisq.test() from the package "pwr" in R. I'll add my calculation to the original question.